# Why can we always choose a partition P

Tags: real-analysis

Why is it that we can always find a partition of a closed interval with $\Delta x_i < \delta$ for example? I understand that it helps if you have a smaller partition to approximate values better, but why do we always have smaller ones available? 
Thanks for any help

Comment: @Masacroso : real numbers can be arbitrarily small, but this has nothing to do with the gaps. Rationals have gaps and yet we can have arbitrarily small rational numbers. Many times we forget that in analysis the power of reals comes not from their density, but from their completeness and on the other hand a large amount of calculation / manipulation in analysis (eg $\epsilon, \delta$ gymnastics) uses only density and not completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $[a,b]$ is the interval in question. Given any real number $\delta>0$, it follows from the Archimedean property of the natural numbers that there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $b-a<n\delta$.

Therefore if we choose the partition 
$$x_i=a+\frac{b-a}{n}i$$
($i=0,1,\dots,n$) of $[a,b]$, then $x_i-x_{i-1}=\frac{b-a}{n}<\delta$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$.